# Fetching users and Geofire query keys take long time with Firebase

Tags: firebase, rxjs, ionic3, angularfire2, geofire

I'm quite new to work with GeoFire and RXJS.

I need to display nearby users based on Geofire query. I tried so many ways, but it take long time, approx 9 segs (just 5-6 test users). How can I optimize it?

Thanks for the help in advance

In firebase

```
-locations
  - userID
      - g
      - l
        - 0:lat
        - 1:long

- users
  -userID
   - firstname: "fname"
   - lastname...
```

Geofire service

> hits = new BehaviorSubject([]);

```
   getNearLocations(radius: number, coords: Array<number>) {
this.geoFire.query({
  center: coords,
  radius: radius
})
.on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => {
  let hit = {
    key: key,
    location: location,
    distance: distance,
  }

  let currentHits = this.hits.value
  //this.hits.push(hit)
  currentHits.push(hit)
  this.hits.next(currentHits)
})
```

people.ts (Constructor)

```
this.locateActiveUser().then((pos) => {
  this.geofire.getNearLocations(2, [pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitud])

  this.subscription = this.geofire.hits  
  .subscribe( nearUserArray => {
    Promise.all(
      nearUserArray.map(nearUser => {              
        this.afDatabase.object(`users/${nearUser.key}`).query.once('value')
        .then( user => {
          nearUser["user"]= user.val(); })        
          return nearUser
    })).then( a => {
      console.log("nearUserArray: ", nearUserArray);
      this.nearbyUsers$ = of(nearUserArray);
    })   

  }) 

})
```

people.html

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let nearby of nearbyUsers$ | async" class="item item-block item-md">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-3 >...
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-9 (click)="navigateTo('user-profile', nearby.user)">
              <ion-row>
                  <ion-col col-4 >
                    <span>A {{nearby.distance | roundNumber }} km</span>
                  </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
              <ion-row>
                <h3> {{nearby.user.firstname}} {{nearby.user["lastname"]}}</h3>
              </ion-row>                      
          </ion-col>    
        </ion-row>
      </ion-item>
```

Browser Console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbJot.png)

Comment: Finally I got it! I add firebase call after each key entered and add each user data to the behavior subject. Additionally, I move getNearLocations to the default tab in the app (first view after logging) Then I just converted the behavior subject value to observable in People.ts. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

So I will say that you are probably doing the best thing you could do.`geofire` is more like an index which you can get references to actual docs/objects in your Firebase RTDB. There are libraries for Firestore such as [`geofirestore`](https://github.com/MichaelSolati/geofirestore) (my personal baby), as well as [`geofirex`](https://github.com/codediodeio/geofirex) that allow you to only make one query based on location and get the doc as well.

`geofirestore` is more similar to `geofire` in regards to how things work under the hood, and may be easier to make the transition to (if you were interested.)